# CustomOverlay for ZXing.Net.Mobile MobileBarcodeScanner

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I am currently unable to apply a CustomOverlay to my MobileBarcodeScanner instance and according the documentation on their website, I should be able to but it gives me the following error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'MobileBarcodeScanner' does not contain a definition for 'CustomOverlay' and no extension method 'CustomOverlay' accepting a first argument of type 'MobileBarcodeScanner' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ScannerTesting  C:\Users\kalpr\Source\Repos\ScannerTesting\ScannerTesting\ScannerTesting\MainViewModel.cs   88  Active

I am doing this in my .Net Standard Class library which shares the code between all the different platforms.

Should I be doing this natively for each platform or can I just declare it in the portable .NET Standard project?

Comment: You can define a Xamarin.Forms-based overlay : https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/fe55346b8e678d2bc90985a8722e4000c3ce1e7d/Samples/Forms/Core/HomePage.cs#L45